# Attribute a role to a user

Tags: angular, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm working on a application with mongodb, spring boot, and angular 4.

I've created two collection in my db: user and role, I just finished the crud of the role object, and now, I want to add a user witch I should specify his role.
I've created the html interface for the user add, and I've displayed the role's list with checkbox, but I don't know what I have to do next?

I have to get the role's object list or I have to get only the title of a role?
what I have to do in frontend and backend ? cause I have no idea?

Answer (score 0):

Now you need controllers ([quick guide to controllers](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers)). Have a controller *RequestMapping(value="/add")* (it doesn't have to be exactly */add*, you can name it whatever you want) that sends 2 models: an user object and the list of roles - for the list you need to fetch the data from the database. In order to do this, you need to know what [JPA](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories)  is and how [services](https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html) work. And return to the HTML page you've created. Now you need a view template engine to help you display the data. I'd choose between [JSP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) or [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html). They are both great.

Now for the second controller, you do the same thing. Annotate it *RequestMapping* and above it *PostMapping* (or instead you can use *@PostMapping*). Your parameter should be (*@ModelAttribute("user") User user*) (the model attribute's name matches the model's name we sent at the first controller). Why do we need the *@ModelAttribute*? Well, we've sent an empty user object at the first controller, now since we would like to add a user to the database, then we are expecting a user object. Why we don't need *Model model* just like at the first controller? Because we are not sending anything to the front. Now you need a method in your user service to save the user object. That's pretty much it.

Read what I've sent you. Don't worry if you don't get it at first (I'm sure you will!). There are plenty of videos on youtube as well on how controllers work.
Happy codding!

EDIT: You need a rest controller to send the data to Angular ([spring and angular](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/))

Comment: I'm so grateful for your response, it's not my first project with spring, but it's the fist time that i work with mongodb. what I want to do is to affect for a user a list of roles, which i choose the roles from checkbox list. the pb is i don't whant to take the hole role object with the web service, but i only want to get the title of the role. someone recommand to use Gson but i didn't like it. is there an other way?